# More than one style as style prop in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder if there is any possibility to have more than one style in React component e.g.

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {

 const styles = {
   styleOne: {
      color: 'red'
   },
   styleTwo: {
      fontSize: '2rem'
   }
 };

 return (
  <div style={styles.styleOne}>
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
 );
}
```

I want `div` to have both `styleOne` and `styleTwo` styles. I have try to pass array of styles to `style` props, but its not working.

Comment: `style={{ ...styles.styleOne, ...styles.styleTwo }}`?

Comment: Thats, what I want. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
export default function App() {

   const styles = {
     styleOne: {
        color: 'red'
     },
     styleTwo: {
        fontSize: '2rem'
     }
   };

   return (
    <div style={{...styles.styleOne, ...styles.styleTwo}}>
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
   );
  }
```

Comment: The comma operator would only pass the second style, surely?